# paypal recurring payment status "Expired"

Tags: html, paypal, recurring-billing

I have integrated a recurring payment section in my site:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="freelancecoachpro@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Total Connect">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.59">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1385616401:1:6:b09c926d4df9a5f17221e56cbe688297">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://119.18.51.11/freelancecoach/thank-you">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://119.18.51.11/freelancecoach/paymentreturn/paypalexpress">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="0"><!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

But the issue is that the PayPal payment profile has been expired after the payment.
Also i have got a mail that is :

> You successfully canceled the following PayPal Recurring Payment profile. We will no longer bill the buyer. If you did not request this cancellation, contact PayPal Customer Support toll-free at 1-888-221-1161.

Also, I have checked the PayPal account which I used to pay for the package, and I saw the status of this recurring payment is “expired”.

My requirement is to subscribe the PayPal account until the subscription cancelled by the account holder. There is no expiring date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `src` to 0, which means subscription payments do not recur.
Additionally, you'll probably also want to look at `srt` and `sra`

Details are available in the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), but basically `srt` determines the number of recurring periods and `sra` whether or not you'd like for us to reattempt charging the buyer after a failure to bill or not.